# Переопределение ToString в собственном классе

Tags: c#

Есть класс `Polynom`. В нем многочлен задается массивом коэффициентов. нужно вывести многочлен в консоль в виде, например, 3x^4+2x^3+1, используя `String.format`.

Класс выглядит так:

```
public class Polynom
{
    public int[] coefficients;
    public int polynomDegree;
    public string x;
    public int[] powers;

    // задать полином при помощи коэффициентов
    public Polynom(params int[] coefficients)
    {
        this.coefficients = coefficients;
    }


    //свойство степени многочлена
    public int PolynomDegree
    {
        get
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < coefficients.Length; i++)
            { powers[i] = i; }
            return powers.Length - 1;
        }
    }




    public override string ToString()
    {
        object[] args = new object[] { this.coefficients, this.powers };
        return string.Format("Polynom  {0}" + "x^{1}", string.Join("" + "x^", args));

    }


    //индексатор на чтение и запись
    public int this[int index]
    {
        set
        {
            this.coefficients[index] = value;
        }

        get
        {
            return this.coefficients[index];
        }
    }
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70046/discussion-on-question-by-fiorie--tostring---).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Так просто через `string.Format()` здесь не получится, он не работает с переменным количеством аргументов.

Мой вариант с использованием `StringBuilder`:

```
class Polynom
{
    //int[] coefficients = new int[] { 1, 2, -6, 2, 3 };
    ...

    public override string ToString()
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = coefficients.Length - 1; i >= 0; --i)
        {
            if (coefficients[i] == 0) continue;
            if (coefficients[i] > 0 && sb.Length > 0) sb.Append('+');
            if (coefficients[i] < 0) sb.Append('-');
            var abs = Math.Abs(coefficients[i]);
            if (abs != 1 || i == 0) sb.Append(abs);
            if (i > 0) sb.Append('x');
            if (i > 1) sb.Append('^').Append(i);
        }
        if (sb.Length == 0) return "0";
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

Учтено:
1. Члены с нулевым коэффициентом не выводятся.
2. Корректно отображается знак `+`/`-` перед коэффициентом, если старший коэффициент положительный — `+` перед ним не отображается.
3. Не отображается степень при `x^1`.
4. Не отображается `x^0` при свободном члене.
5. Если все коэффициенты равны `0` — отображается `0`.
6. Коэффициент `1`/`-1` отображается только для свободного члена

Пример вывода: `3x^4+2x^3-6x^2+2x+1`

Comment: ого. такой вариант не видела еще. спасибо огромное.

Comment: @Fiorie, обновил ответ — учел еще один небольшой нюанс.

Answer (score 2):

Переопределяете метод `ToString()`. Берете массив коэффициентов, собираете из них строки вида `cx^i` и разворачиваете так, чтобы старший коэффициент шел первым. Добавляете костыль для 0-й степени. Примерно так:

```
class Polynom
{
    int[] coefficients = new int[] { 1, 0, 0, 2, 3 };

    public override string ToString()
    {
        var nonZero = String.Join(" + ", 
            coefficients
                .Where(c => c != 0)
                .Select((i, c) =>  $"{c}x^{i + 1}")
                .Skip(1) // skip x^0
                .Reverse());

        return nonZero + (coefficients[0] != 0 ? " + " + coefficients[0] : "");
    }
}
```

Comment: Отрицательные коэффициенты не учтены!

Comment: @Андрей, почему эт?

Comment: ну будет типа `5x^2 + -3x^1`, первая степень, кстати, тоже должна быть опущена, @Grundy

Comment: @Андрей у топикастера тоже нет отрицательных. первую степень - на усмотрение топикастера, пусть дорабатывает, если она ему мешает :)