# Реализация класса для одномерного списка

Tags: c#, односвязный-список

Есть следующий код для создания односвязного списка. Зачем нужна последняя конструкция "ToString"? Какую функцию она выполняет?

```
class Point
{
    public string data;//информационное поле 
    public Point next;//адресное поле 

    public Point()//конструктор без параметров 
    {
        data = null;
        next = null;
    }

    public Point(string d)//конструктор с параметрами 
    {
        data = d;
        next = null;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return data + " ";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Очевидно, метод служит для получения строкового представления экземпляра класса. Этот метод автоматически вызывается, например, при выводе элемента через `Console.WriteLine(...)`, при формировании строки через `string.Format(...)` (или в C# 6.0+ через формирование через интерполяцию `$"..."`), при привязке элементов в WPF, если вы явно не переопределите `DataTemplate`, а также при просмотре свойств объекта в отладчике.

Если вы явно не переопределите метод `ToString` у своего класса, то будет использована реализация родительского класса, при этом реализация в классе `Object` возвращает полное имя типа.

Вот тема с примерами перегрузки метода для класса, представляющего многочлен: [Переопределение ToString в собственном классе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/756712/218063)

MSDN: [Метод Object.ToString()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.object.tostring(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Если класс переопределяет функцию ToString, то она будет использоваться там где объекту требуется преобразование в строку. Например если вызвать

```
var p = new Point("test point");
Console.WriteLine($"Point: '{p}'");
```

то будет напечатано `Point: 'test point '`, если бы переопределения не было, то реализация метода `ToString` "по умолчанию":

```
public virtual String ToString()
{
    return GetType().ToString();
}
```

выведет имя типа. Переопределение `ToString` удобно и полезно в целях отладки и логирования, чтобы объект мог иметь вменяемое строкое представление.